# DynamoDB spikes higher than defined capacity units and strong consistency not working

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

We have defined RCU & WCU with min 40 and max 50 units and we have a job that does performance testing, the job over here will call one of the Rest API endpoint and the endpoint does the batchwrite operation, so we ran the job with 40TPS and it writes into each table, all the tables are below the required defined units however two of the tables spikes with double the size than defined, all the code logic is same for all tables, not sure what is happenning over here, can some help?

```
public async Task BatchWriteAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities, DynamoDBOperationConfig dynamoDBOperationConfig)
        {
                var result = context.CreateBatchWrite<T>(dynamoDBOperationConfig);
                result.AddPutItems(entities);
                await result.ExecuteAsync();            
        }
```

In performance we identified that there is one more issue, we know that in eventual consistency when we try to get the record immediately, it fails, so, we went with the strong consistency for read and the result is same, it still gives a 404 error, can someone help whether our understanding is incorrect?

`customer = customers.get_item(hash_key="42", consistent_read=True)`

Comment: Are you saying some of your tables are showing double the consumed write capacity units? Are you writing the same data to all tables?

Comment: For read consistency, you're using async operations, are you awaiting the 200 response before attempting to read. Also a read to DynamoDB will not return 404 when reading an item that does not exist.

Comment: @LeeHannigan The data is different however the size is almost same i.e. up to or less than 1kb.

Comment: @LeeHannigan For Read, after creating record if I try to get it immediately using hash key then it's not found but if I try it later than it's available, this is seen in performance testing when the read is immediately after the create.

Answer (score 0):

The throughput being different is likely caused by your item size. As you mention it's approx 1KB, if a write as 1byte over 1KB then it will consume 2 WCU which is double the consumption of any items smaller than 1KB.

For strongly consistent read, I guarantee that if you wait to get a 200 response from DynamoDB that a strongly consistent read will find the item, DynamoDB is built in a way that it would be impossible to not return it if your client logic is correct.